# Validation process of a config-file for a cli-tool: Avoiding nested if's

Tags: clojure

Consider this quite nested piece of clojure code, which describes the validation process of an edn-config file which is passed to a commandline tool.

```
(defn -main [& [config-path]]
  (if config-path
    (if-let [content (read-file config-path)]
      (if-let [raw-data (read-edn content)]
        (if-let [parsed (parse raw-data)]
          (start-processing parsed)
          (error "parsing-error"))
        (error "invalid-edn-format"))
      (error "file-not-found"))
    (error "no argument"))
```

*Note: The invoked functions are dummies*

This calls for less nested & less imperative ways to do so. Do you have any suggestions for improvements here?

The above function can be boiled down to actually 4 validation functions, which are invoked in a chain: (1) Argument-Check, (2) File-Read, (3) Parse-EDN, (4) Parse-Data. They differ in the way they treat "errors": For 1 and 4 I'm using clojure.spec, hence :clojure.spec/invalid is returned on a fail. The others (2 and 3) would throw an exception, when something is wrong.
This makes it particularly difficult to abstract here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Either` monad.

At first you need to modify your functions to return `Either`:

```
(require '[cats.monad.either :as either])

(defn assert-config-path-e [config-path]
  (if config-path
    (either/right config-path)
    (either/left "no argument")))

(defn read-file-e [config-path]
  ;; interpret return value as error
  (if-let [content (read-file config-path)]
    (either/right content)
    (either/left "file-not-found")))

(defn read-edn-e [content]
  (try
    (read-edn content)
    (catch ...
      ;; interpret thrown exception as error
      (either/left "invalid-edn-format"))))

(defn parse-e [raw-data]
  (if-let [parsed (parse raw-data)]
    (either/right parsed)
    (either/left "parsing-error")))
```

`Right` value represents successful computation, `Left` - error that has happened.

After that combine all the stuff using `do`-notation/`mlet`:

```
(require '[cats.core :as cats])

(defn -main [& [config-path]]
  (cats/mlet [_ (assert-config-path-e config-path)
              content (read-file-e config-path)
              raw-data (read-edn-e content)
              parsed (parse-e raw-data)]
    (cats/return (start-processing parsed)))
```

Comment: This looks like a clean thing. Two questions: Your code does not state at any point, what should be done with the error strings, (e.g. printing them). As well as: Why cats? Could it be done with clojure.algo.monads, too? Thanks for the effort!

Comment: @AntonHarald I've used cats in the example, because we have been using it in production for quite a while. I didn't quite get your question regarding error strings: if error occured during pipeline, `left` value would be returned containing, usually, error object (in this implementation it is string describing the error). This functionality can be implemented using `algo.monads`, but `algo.monads` library doesn't have implementation of `Either` monad, so you'd need to implement it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Using `delay` defers evaluation but allows values to be bound to local `let` variables.  Using `and` next evaluates the expression, but will short-circuit on `nil`, which is what you want.  `cond` then will give specific error messages, and evaluate your final step if there were no errors.

```
(defn -main [& [config-path]]
  (let [content  (delay (read-file config-path))
        raw-data (delay (read-edn @content))
        parsed   (delay (parse @raw-data))]
    (and config-path
         @content
         @raw-data
         @parsed)
    (cond
      (nil? config-path) (error "no argument")
      (nil? @content)    (error "file-not-found")
      (nil? @raw-data)   (error "invalid-edn-format")
      (nil? @parsed)     (error "parsing-error")
      :else (start-processing @parsed))))
```

It has these advantages:

- it's flatter
- easy to understand (maybe, once you get past `delay`?)
- leaves called functions alone, not forcing them to do things which are not within their definition, maintaining the purity of the functions
- does not involve macros (not a bad thing, but using core functions is a plus)

Answer (score 0):

I would consider writing separate functions for each part of the logic so they can deal with validation and use a consistent means of reporting errors (in this case exceptions):

```
(defn validate-config-path [config-path]
  (if config-path
    config-path
    (throw ...)))

(defn read-raw-config [config-path]
  (try
    (read-file config-path)
    (catch ...
      (throw ...))))

(defn read-edn-config [raw-config]
  (try
    ...
    (catch ...
      (throw ...))))

(defn read-parsed-config [edn-config]
  (try
    ...
    (catch ...
      (throw ...))))

(defn -main [& [config-path]]
  (try
    (-> config-path
        validate-config-path
        read-edn-config
        read-parsed-config)
    (catch Exception e
      (error (.getMessage e)))))
```

With this approach you can easily test each part separately (as its encapsulated in a separate function) and reuse it in other places. You also centralise how you handle displaying errors to user in one place so you can change how you present programmatic error to the user.